# installing vim latex on top of yard

Tags: vim-latex

Has anyone succeeded in installing vim-latex plugin on top of yadr settings?

As suggested in

https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/doc/vim/manage_plugins.md

I tried using

$ yav -u https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex

and adding the recommended settings to my .vimrc file as instructed in

http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html#recommended-settings

Naively, this completes the installation.

However, there should be something wrong as I cannot compile a simple tex file inside vim normal mode. More precisely, normal mode vim does not allows me to type \ll. So I assume that the installation is wrong or incomplete ... So any advice is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: What errors come up when you try using \ll? If nothing at all, could you post the output of `:map \ll`?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answeing. 
:map \ll yields
No mapping found and :scriptnames yields
231: ~/.yadr/vim/bundle/vim-latex/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim
...
254: ~/.yadr/vim/bundle/vim-latex/ftplugin/latex-suite/packages/amsmath
Any comments or clues are very welcome.

Comment: How about the output of `:map ,ll`? It looks like YADR makes your leader comma rather than backslash.

Comment: Many thanks, you are right! Replacing backslash by comma makes vim-latex work normally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beggining of the vimrc for YADR, they remap the "leader" for plugins to comma.

Thus, the shortcut you're looking for is `,ll`.